# Select rows based on specific time interval per day between range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have following data which has minute by minute updates. I want to select and create a data from a CSV file based on specific time interval per day between a time range.

For instance between year `2021 - 2019` for every given day, I want to collect values at every `45 mins` and create a new dataframe with selected rows for `2021 - 2019`

So first record I will collect will be at `00:45:00`

`1413698,1610585100000,2021-01-14 00:45:00,ETHUSD,1570.0122,1570.0122,2166.6168359999997,1569.405,81.20277324`

And the second will be `01:30:00`

`1413698,1610585100000,2021-01-14 01:30:00,ETHUSD,1570.0122,1570.0122,2166.6168359999997,1569.405,81.20277324`

I have both `Timestamp` and `Date`

I did take a look at [`at_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at_time.html#pandas-dataframe-at-time) and [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html#pandas-dataframe-between-time) but I am not entirely sure how to make it dynamic... I am working with a very large dataset of 10m records.

....

```
,Unix Timestamp,Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
1413684,1610585940000,2021-01-14 00:59:00,ETHUSD,1561.6632,1568.8805999999997,2165.0552279999993,1566.645,36.88621233
1413685,1610585880000,2021-01-14 00:58:00,ETHUSD,1562.5739999999998,1565.0441999999998,2159.7609959999995,1561.6632,10.125155
1413686,1610585820000,2021-01-14 00:57:00,ETHUSD,1563.2915999999998,1563.5675999999999,2157.7232879999997,1562.5739999999998,2.292847
1413687,1610585760000,2021-01-14 00:56:00,ETHUSD,1559.7174,1563.471,2157.5899799999997,1563.2915999999998,19.067405
1413688,1610585700000,2021-01-14 00:55:00,ETHUSD,1563.0432,1563.0432,2156.999616,1559.7174,23.192
1413689,1610585640000,2021-01-14 00:54:00,ETHUSD,1563.2225999999998,1563.2225999999998,2157.247188,1563.0432,1.182948
1413690,1610585580000,2021-01-14 00:53:00,ETHUSD,1565.0717999999997,1565.0717999999997,2159.7990839999993,1563.2225999999998,0.44687991
1413691,1610585520000,2021-01-14 00:52:00,ETHUSD,1567.0728,1567.0728,2162.5604639999997,1565.0717999999997,4.9634
1413692,1610585460000,2021-01-14 00:51:00,ETHUSD,1568.6598,1568.6598,2164.7505239999996,1567.0728,50.812107
1413693,1610585400000,2021-01-14 00:50:00,ETHUSD,1569.7913999999998,1570.8953999999999,2167.8356519999998,1568.6598,9.52937829
1413694,1610585340000,2021-01-14 00:49:00,ETHUSD,1573.1999999999998,1573.1999999999998,2171.0159999999996,1569.7913999999998,23.994037
1413695,1610585280000,2021-01-14 00:48:00,ETHUSD,1573.1724,1573.9314,2172.0253319999997,1573.1999999999998,9.270839
1413696,1610585220000,2021-01-14 00:47:00,ETHUSD,1571.1989999999998,1573.2551999999998,2171.0921759999997,1573.1724,4.777295
1413697,1610585160000,2021-01-14 00:46:00,ETHUSD,1569.405,1571.2541999999999,2168.3307959999997,1571.1989999999998,24.769021
1413698,1610585100000,2021-01-14 00:45:00,ETHUSD,1570.0122,1570.0122,2166.6168359999997,1569.405,81.20277324
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/CF17544/Desktop/table1.csv", index_col=[0], converters={'Date':lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x)})
# Create series with 45 minute interval, starting at 2019-01-01T00:45:00
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 45, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31), freq='45T')})
# Merge both
df3 = df.merge(df2, on='Date')
```